# Why does my vector need a constant value?

Tags: c++, vector, graph, adjacency-list

I'm trying to make an adjacency list graph implementation using vectors. In my vector declaration, I keep getting an error of "expression must have a constant value." I don't understand why I get this error, as I thought that vectors were already dynamic arrays and this wouldn't be a problem.

```
int nodes = 5;

vector<int> adjacencyList[nodes];
```

Comment: You're trying to construct a raw array with 5 `std::vector`s. If you want to constructor a `std::vector` with 5 elements, it should be `vector<int> adjacencyList(nodes);`.

Comment: That's not a vector. That's an array of vectors.

Comment: *I thought that vectors were already dynamic arrays* -- Well, given this statement, why would you try to declare a vector using the array syntax, i.e. `[nodes]`  if a vector is a dynamic array already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of an **array** variable must be compile time constant, regardless of the type of the element of the array.

It is somewhat unclear whether your array declaration was intentional. If you want a dynamic array of vectors, then what you could use instead is a vector of vectors. If your intention was to create a single vector, then don't use the square brackets since the square brackets are syntax for an array. Here is an example of how to initialise a single vector of particular size:

```
std::vector<int> adjacencyList(nodes);
```